# Many apps just disappeared from my machine after low storage warnings?

Tags: hard-drive, applications, filesystem, error, disk-space

I was using my Mac last night, and at some point I got a warning that my disk had filled up. I checked Macintosh HD, and it reported having over 5GB free, so I ignored the warning. I started to notice that I was unable to open some apps from the Dock, but didn't need them at the time.

I restarted the computer this morning, and suddenly a large number of apps have simply disappeared from my Applications folder, and the free space on my drive is now up to 30GB, which is horrifying. Does anyone know what could have happened or what steps I should take to ensure that no other data has been lost?